# How to convert a Java applet to a web application?

Tags: java, web-applications, applet

I have a Java applet that I want to convert to a web application. Is there any solution to convert the application?

If the solution is step-wise then it will be easy to implement.

Comment: _Is there is any solution to convert the application_ Yes, write corresponding code using web technologies like JSP, JSF etc. There's no automated way to convert it.

Comment: @Simze Yes ( No ) :D

Answer (score 0):

you can directly load applet in jsp page using jsp:plugin tag.
for that first you have to create .jar file (bean) for the applet.
then using jsp page and jsp:plugin tag to load the applet.

```
<jsp:plugin type="applet" codebase="yourapplet.jar" code="appletexample.AppletExample" width="400" height="400">
```

---

Comment: Please do not post your personal contact info in public.